# Tips to ask a question based on selected tags and reputation

Tags: feature-request

I saw countless questions which don't provide any usable information to help or a way to see what a person already did (like: *I'm using jQuery to create a datepicker, but it doesn't work, where's the problem?*)

I'd like to see some tips until a user gained some reputation (e.g. 500) like *Don't forget to provide sample code and steps to reproduce!* etc. it's really annoying to refer to the FAQs (it should be the first to read).

And I'd like to see tips related to the selected tags. Example:

*Javascript/HTML/CSS Tip:*

> Did you remember to provide a live demo?

I know we're not in the kindergarden, but StackOverflow could increase many questions, which will help to answer a question within a shorter time.

(And we could decrease the number of redirects to http://whathaveyoutried.com/ if you know what I mean.)

It should be also possible to include this to the Stack Exchange engine to provide those functions to everyone.

---

**Update:** I see the idea with JSFiddle isn't the best, but it should show in which direction we could guide new members. We could add a tip for programming language-tags which says *Did you remember to include errors and stacktraces if your app crashed?*

So the idea would be to **help to remember the important things** in a good question. *A tip isn't a requirement.*

Summary:

- Add tips for new users to show how they can improve their questions to get better and faster answers.
- Add tips until a new user got a minimum of reputation (e.g. 500).
- Add tips in general (e.g. *Did you read your question again?*) and to specific tags, which points to specific improvements (e.g. for programming languages: *Did you remember to debug your application?*).
- Tips aren't requirements!
- A tip will help to improve questions, not to make them perfect.

Comment: Tip is with a single "p" and stay with a single "p" when pluralized.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my native language is German, so I'm always confused about the correct spelling. Thank you.

Comment: While this may reduce the WhatHaveYouTried it may increase the pro forma comment *In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.*

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I see what you mean. I added some new thoughts.